# Checking if there is a URL for the Back button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I've a little problem with a jQuery Mobile app I'm building. I have page where a back button using `data-rel="back`. It works well except in one case :

These page can be access by a link from an e-mail. So, when you come from the e-mail, the back button will not work.

So, is there a way to test if there is a previous URL or if the user comes from an e-mail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check for the data-rel='back' attribute?

```
$("a:jqmData(rel='back')").length
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/KHhv4/4/ (loading normally)
- http://jsfiddle.net/KHhv4/5/ (Loading page2 first to mimic email)

Answer (score 0):

OK maybe this is a better option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-rel="back"]').hide();
})

$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('a[data-rel="back"]').show();
});
```